# What does it mean about database logic?

Tags: mysql

I try to understand this code , but I failed , anybody help~

```
CAST(
 CONCAT(
  CAST(
   CASE WHEN IFNULL(SM.start_date,'') = '' THEN'1911/01/01'ELSE SM.start_date END AS CHAR(10)
  ) ,'',
  CAST(CASE WHEN IFNULL(SM.start_time,'') = '' THEN'00:00:00'ELSE SM.start_time END AS CHAR(8)
  )
 ) 
AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Instead of just downvoting new people, tell them at least what they did wrong... Everything else is dumb. So I assume that you should write what you so far think it means. Did you try to give it data and just launch it? Cause you dont need to ask a question like this, simple put it into your SQL Browser and launch it with hard coded properties and you will see what happens.

Comment: @Cataklysim This is the tooltip for the downvote button: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful* What more explanation is needed?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen maybe tell him what exactly he did wrong. Feedback is always good. I know, the start is always rough but we can be a great community and maybe just take a minute and explain why. Thats what we do with questions, so why not with downvotes? Like, just tell him that he can easily test it by himself. Done. Everyone is happy.

Comment: now I know that is not a good way to ask this question , sorry ,I will improve

Comment: @Cataklysim Downvoting helps separate the wheat from the chaff for others looking for help or looking to help. Personally, I try not to downvote well-meaning questions (though I may vote to close), but I can understand people becoming jaded by the constant influx of crappy questions. When you stick around a while, it becomes almost a reflex to try to clear out the junk ASAP.

Comment: @shmosel comprehensibly. I may be too "new" and thats why I find it so unfair... But even if its a little frustrating seeing so many bad questions, it won't improve if we don't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is getting the date part of Start_Date and the time part of Start_Time and joining them together using CONCAT to make a datetime variable.
If start_date is blank it is setting the date to '1911/01/01'
If the start_time is blank it is setting it to '00:00:00'

```
CAST(  --CONVERT TO A DIFFERT TYPE
 CONCAT(  --JOIN 2 OR MORE STRINGS TOGETHER
  CAST(   
   CASE WHEN IFNULL(SM.start_date,'') = '' THEN'1911/01/01'ELSE SM.start_date END AS CHAR(10)  --IF BLANK SET TO ........OR ELSE TAKE THE FIRST 10 CHARACTERS
  ) ,'',
  CAST(CASE WHEN IFNULL(SM.start_time,'') = '' THEN'00:00:00'ELSE SM.start_time END AS CHAR(8)  --IF BLANK SET TO ........OR ELSE TAKE THE FIRST 8 CHARACTERS
  )
 ) 
AS DATETIME)
```

However - not a good approach and I don't think it would work correctly.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "date part" and "time part"; it is taking all of both fields.  it should work fine, so long as those fields are actually a date and a time, respectively, and assuming the `''` in the middle is really `' '` in the real code.

Comment: it's my senior get that to me , want me to rewrite with Laravel

Answer (score 0):

A pseduo-code translation will be:

- If `SM.start_date` is `NULL`, then consider `SM.start_date` as `1911/01/01`, else use `SM.start_date` itself.
  `CAST` the resultant expression as a 10 character string (to accommodate `yyyy/mm/dd`).

Likewise,

- If `SM.start_time` is `NULL`, then consider `SM.start_time` as `00:00:00`, else use `SM.start_time` itself.
  `CAST` the resultant expression as a 8 character string (to accommodate `hh:mm:ss`).

Concatenate the two expressions from the above and call the final string as `DATETIME`

Comment: if start_date and start_time are actually char types (admittedly unlikely, but we don't actually know), it will use the 1911/01/01 and 00:00:00 defaults if they are either '' or null, not just null

Comment: Thanks @ysth. Yes, I tried to simplify the translation of `IFNULL(SM.start_date,'') = ''` and ignore `""` just for the sake of the explanation here. Although, I totally concur with the remark above.